# Plotting a chart from org table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

org mode is  very good in plotting table. But is there any way of creating line plot from the table directly in org mode?

Comment: Have you looked into org-plot/gnuplot ?

Comment: It require external program.

Comment: So what? You'd hardly want to stuff emacs with every capability under the sun. External programs exist, thank goodness, so use them. Not everything that needs to be done, needs to be done by emacs alone.

Comment: You can try `orgtbl-ascii-plot.el` ;) [orgtbl-ascii-plot.el – plots in ascii-art](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37836/plotting-a-chart-from-org-table)